# Why Isn't my Swift code working?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I have written a piece of code in my app which is supposed to generate a random number from 1-10 and my images are all named 1-10. It then is supposed to display that image on the screen in a UIImageView. Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var QuoteImage: UIImageView!

    func randomImagePicker() {
        var QuoteImages: [UIImage] {
            var QuoteImages: [UIImage] = []
            // Create images named 1 - 10
            let randomImageIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(10) + 1)
            // Assign the image property of the imageView to the element behind the random index in the images array
            self.QuoteImage.image = QuoteImages[randomImageIndex]
            let image = UIImage(named: "\(randomImageIndex)")!
            QuoteImages.append(image)
            // Create a random index
            return QuoteImages
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Display “that image”? Which one? The first one? You have an array of images, so I’m unclear which you want to show...

Comment: The randomly Generated Image

Comment: But I'm not getting why `QuoteImages` is an array. Shouldn't it just be single `UIImage` rather than `[UIImage]`? And then you can set the `image` property of `QuoteImage` to be that image you selected.

Comment: (BTW, completely unrelated, but by convention, variables like `QuoteImage` and `QuoteImages` should start with lowercase letters.) And personally, to avoid confusion between the image and the image view, I'd define the image view to be `quoteImageView` and the randomly selected image to be `quoteImage` (which would just be a `UIImage`, not a `[UIImage]`).

Comment: How do you do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest simply getting the index and then setting the `image` property of the image view accordingly:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var quoteImageView: UIImageView!

    func randomImagePicker() {
        let index = Int(arc4random_uniform(10) + 1)
        quoteImageView.image = UIImage(named: "\(index)")!
    }
}
```

If you need the array for some other purpose, explain what your intent was and we can clarify how you might achieve that. But if you're just trying to set the `image` of the image view to be some random image, the above should suffice.

Comment: Thank you, will this display the image in the view?

Comment: Yes, when you call `randomImagePicker`, it should set the image. Frankly, I don't see how your code wouldn't have crashed with "subscript out of range" (you set `self.QuoteImage.image = QuoteImages[randomImageIndex]` before you added any images to your array). And even if it didn't, you set `self.QuoteImage.image` _before_ you retrieved `UIImage(named: "\(randomImageIndex)")!`. You should just retrieve the `UIImage` and set the `image` property of your image view accordingly.

Comment: It won't call properly

Comment: expected Declaration

Comment: Note, I changed the name of the outlet to be `quoteImageView`. Did you change this to match the name of your outlet (or did you change the name of your outlet to match this)?

Comment: Then there's something else wrong with your project. Setting the `image` for a `UIImageView` is as trivial as shown above. But without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem, we won't be able to help you further.

Comment: my code is as you put it, so I don't know what is wrong

Comment: I wonder if you’ve added the images correctly. Is it finding the image? Are they in the bundle? Are they in assets library? Where are they located?

Comment: The Assets library